# Why does my AppHarbor site randomly take over 10 seconds to respond

Tags: appharbor

I have a Pingdom check that runs every 5 minutes and it reports that the average response time of my site slows right down seemingly randomly. The site is still in development so not being used. It's an ASP.NET MVC site with NHibernate and using the "Shared Microsoft SQL Server as a service" addon. What could be causing this?

Pingdom report data:

00:00–01:00 266 ms
01:00–02:00 5,459 ms
02:00–03:00 336 ms
03:00–04:00 267 ms
04:00–05:00 275 ms
05:00–06:00 334 ms
06:00–07:00 513 ms
07:00–08:00 11,663 ms
08:00–09:00 316 ms
09:00–10:00 4,680 ms
10:00–11:00 350 ms
11:00–12:00 10,234 ms
12:00–13:00 2,866 ms
13:00–14:00 263 ms
14:00–15:00 309 ms
15:00–16:00 308 ms
16:00–17:00 5,261 ms
17:00–18:00 5,121 ms
18:00–19:00 6,873 ms
19:00–20:00 315 ms
20:00–21:00 ?    No data for this day
21:00–22:00 405 ms
22:00–23:00 346 ms
23:00–24:00 413 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick reply from AppHarbor support who sorted out the problem. It was some sort of bug with my server instance where it had 2 workers. The slow Pingdom responses are likely to be where the request was handled by a "cold" worker.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default is for IIS to restart your application pool every 29 hours, so you might be seeing slow first requests generated by pingdom if you site is not seeing a lot of traffic other than what Pingdom generates.